# jQuery basics - selector

Tags: jquery

I feel dumb.. Why is my "header" div not being selected? Its background color is not being changed. **I am learning about the + operator so I am not looking for a different selector.**

E + F : an F element immediately preceded by an E element

In this case the div tag is immediately preceded by the div with id divA but it is not selected.

```
$("#divA + div").css("background-color", "red");
```

Html

```
<div id="divA">
        <div>
            Header</div>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
        printing and typesetting industry.
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Of course it was dumb. Thanks to all that answered. I have voted everyone up but can only pick one answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
$("#divA > div").css("background", "red");
```

`>` is the child selector. It's saying find me all `<div>` elements that are direct children of the element with ID of `divA`. When you write `$("#divA + div")` you're saying "find me the `<div>` that immediately follows the `<div>` with ID `divA`. `+` means "next sibling".

To clarify:

```
<div id="divA">
  <div>child</div>
</div>
<div>next</div>
```

So:

```
$("#divA > div") // child
$("#divA + div") // next
```

Comment: @rkrauter because the inner div is a child not a sibling.

Comment: not correct. "find me the `<div>` that immediately follows the *sibling* `<div>` with ID `divA`"

Comment: @ghoppe hows that not what I said?

Comment: @cletus looks good after your clarification. I don't think i saw your last sentence there when i first posted.

Comment: So to find the very first decendant, I would do $("#divA > div:first"), correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rkrauter: Yep this should do it.

Answer (score 1):

E + F is an F element immediately preceded by a *sibling* E element.

Your header div is a *child* element of your #divA element.

Comment: +1 @OP: More: http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#sibling-combinators

Answer (score 1):

*E + F an F element immediately preceded by an E element* means that it will select *F* if *E* is the **preceding sibling**.
E.g. your HTML would have to look like this in order to make the selector work:

```
<div id="divA">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
        printing and typesetting industry.
</div>
<div>Header</div>
```

---

Otherwise you have to use a child or descendant relationship:

```
$('#divA div').css("background-color", "red");
```